# Can I transpile a react component to a web component?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, web-component

I am working on a big angular project and want to use some react components, but since react components can't be used in angular in a proper way, I wonder if I can transpile the react component to a web component and then include the web component in my angular project.

Comment: "since react components can't be used in angular in a proper way" - depends upon what you mean by "proper" -- you can certainly create Angular components that render a React component tree under them (using either `ReactDOM.render()` or clever use of React portals).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution (from [Rect DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html#using-react-in-your-web-components))**

Encapsulate *React* in a w*eb component*, then use the web component in your *Angular* app.
This should fullfill both your requirement:

- you do not need to rewrite the parent Angular app
- you do not need to rewrite the child React components

#### Example:

```
    class XSearch extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        const mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(mountPoint);

        const name = this.getAttribute('name');
        const url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(name);
        ReactDOM.render(<a href={url}>{name}</a>, mountPoint);
      }
    }
    customElements.define('x-search', XSearch);
```

Comment: That's not, what I want to, because your solution does not offer any way to create let's say a list of react components by angular.

Comment: You are right, but keep it as separate apps will generate less problem and work than embedding react in angular. There are a lot of projects that are trying to do it (IE: https://github.com/Microsoft/angular-react). But it could make your work harder than rewrite the components or the container app. The most straightforward solution could be a smart use of an iframe pointing to a react app embedded in your angular app. Have a good work, mate

Comment: See my edit after a deeper reading of React docs, this solution seems the best fit

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the react component into a Native Web component without using any frameworks then you can use it in React and Angular and Vue and anything else.

If/When your company wants to move to a different framework then a native component written in raw JavaScript will still function.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but I can't rewrite all the components.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Comment: But what you mentioned was exactly my idea, except the fact that I do not want to rewrite the components, but transpile them, to use them in any framework.

Comment: Maybe you can convince the powers that be to allow native components only moving forward. Helping them understand that there is value in reuse and native is the simplest way to create a component that can be used in any framework.

Answer (score 0):

We can include the React component using `<script>` tag. Please follow the below guide provided in React JS docs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want react as a dependency

Comment: If you don't want to include react as a dependency then you can build that react project so that it would give you the final bundled file which could be included in the script tag.